# Git diff between master and origin/master using Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, diff, git-diff

I have a remote repository (origin) and my local repository.
How to make a diff between my local master and the origin master please?

In the command line I simply write :

```
git diff master origin/master
```

But I do not know how to do this under netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

It will be supported in NB 7.4

See http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB74#Diff_between_revisions_2

Answer (score 0):

On Netbeans Right click a file then go to Git->Diff.

Or also you can right click on the left sidebar on the project, then select
Git->Diff.

Also each file has button on the top that says History.

Hoep this helps.

Comment: M8, you are talking about how to diff among index, HEAD, working tree of the same branch.  But master and origin/master are two separate branches, they just ref each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do, is to create a new branch, work in it, and when you want to compare to current master (which in your case is origin/master, i.e. the version of master that's on your team's central server, you do a pull (which should work cleanly as there should be no changes in your private working branch, and then compare your branch to master.

I have the same problem, being used to CVS and SVN :)