# NetBeans anyway to see the commits not pushed to remote git repo

Tags: git, netbeans

In NetBeans I have a number of commits to my local git repo.
How can I see the commits not pushed to the remote repo?

Comment: I'm not sure about git, but I use Netbeans with some SVN repositories and modified files appear as blue in the editor, un-versioned appear as grey, new appear as green. If that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans does not have this facility yet. Here is a bug that talks about this.
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=208930
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=207165

Take a look at this, 
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#diff

Here is another SF question about this.
[Git diff between master and origin/master using Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788959/netbeans-git-diff-between-master-and-origin-master)

@EM-Creations

Yep, but svn is different. GIT has the concept of Remote and Head (local repo) and a working tree. When you commit you commit to Head and you have to push to remote repo.